# seq<obj> versus seq<float> in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following method:

```
  member this.addColumnWithHeading heading column =
    this.addColumn (seq { yield heading; yield! (column |> Seq.map string)})
```

which takes a string heading and any sequence (which is compiled to seq in this case), creates a sequence of strings and calls another method with this data. However, it doesn't work with column being a sequence of floats:

```
Error   1   The type 'obj' does not match the type 'float'  C:\Users\ga1009\Documents\PhD\cpp\pmi\fsharp\pmi\Program.fs 138
```

How can I define the method `addColumnWithHeading` so that it works with floats as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `string` function is an inline function which uses a statically-resolved generic parameter; since your `addColumnWithHeading` method is not declared `inline`, the F# type inference has to assume the values in the sequence are of type `obj`.

There's a simple solution though -- swap out the `string` function in favor of "manually" calling `.ToString()` on the values in the sequence. If you do that, F# will be able to use a standard generic parameter type for the sequence so you can pass a sequence of any type you desire.

```
member this.addColumnWithHeading heading column =
    seq {
        yield heading
        yield! Seq.map (fun x -> x.ToString()) column }
    |> this.addColumn
```

Comment: `ToString` doesn't always produce the same result as `string`. `string None` is one example.

Comment: @Daniel -- true, but making the method `inline` so you can use `string` instead of `.ToString()` is a drastic over-optimization unless you're absolutely certain the function is only going to be called from a few places in the code and with a few different types. Otherwise, you're going to be inlining a relatively large function all throughout your code -- so you end up with a much larger assembly just to handle a few edge cases.

Comment: Since his method is only one line it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: I just checked the [source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L4084-4100) and there are two differences from `ToString`: `null` returns the empty string and the invariant culture is always used for `IFormattable`s. If those are of no concern then there's no reason to use `inline`.

Answer (score 3):

`string` is inlined so its argument type has to be resolved at compile-time. Since your member is not inlined it picks the most general type it can (`obj` in this case). Inlining your method will allow `column` to remain generic.

```
member inline x.AddColumnWithHeading(heading, column) =
  x.AddColumn(seq { yield heading; yield! Seq.map string column })
```

EDIT

Per the comments to Jack's answer, you might not need to inline your use of `string`. Certainly, if `column` will always be `seq<float>` you should just add a type annotation. Passing `seq<string>` and moving the string conversion outside the function is another option.

Comment: `string` is an `inline` function, but doesn't require any constraint - it works with any statically known type.  The rest of your answer looks good to me.